# retrieve day after tomorrow date query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select day after tomorrow date in sql. Like I want to make a query which select date after two days. If I select today's date from calender(29-04-2015) then it should show date on other textbox as (01-05-2015). I want a query which retrieve day after tomorrow date. So far I have done in query is below:

```
SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM DLG_DEAL WHERE VALUE_DATE = GETDATE()+2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `DATEADD(d, 2, GETDATE())` for SQL Server

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you have a date field containing the time information, you will need to truncate the date part using [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, VALUE_DATE))
```

To compare 2 dates ignoring the date part you could just use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM DLG_DEAL
WHERE datediff(d, VALUE_DATE, getdate()) = -2
```

or

```
SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM DLG_DEAL
WHERE datediff(d, getdate(), VALUE_DATE) = 2
```

Comment: thanks @Sebastien Sevrin I got my answer through your answer. Correct answer is SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM DLG_DEAL
WHERE datediff(d, VALUE_DATE, getdate()) = -2

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
SELECT VALUE_DATE 
FROM DLG_DEAL WHERE VALUE_DATE = convert(varchar(11),(Getdate()+2),105)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5266)**

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE VALUE_DATE = DATEADD(d, 2, GETDATE())`

Comment: thanks for reply Rahul Tripathi but its not working.

Comment: @kamranLadhani:- Can you define `not working`? What is the issue? or may be create a sqlfiddle for your `not working` part

Comment: @RahulTripathi the values are not retrieving even the values are in the table

Comment: @RahulTripathi Error Showing. "The conversion of varchar data type into datetime datatype resulted an out-of-range value".  :)

Comment: @kamranLadhani:- Got the issue. Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM DLG_DEAL WHERE datediff(d, VALUE_DATE, getdate()) = -2
```

Answer (score 1):

** I think you should try this**

```
       SELECT DATEADD(day,2,VALUE_DATE) AS DayAfterTomorrow
       FROM DLG_DEAL WHERE VALUE_DATE= GETDATE();
```

**DATEADD(choiceToAdd, interval, date)**

This function allows you to add or substract day,month, year,etc from date. In this interval is nothing but numeric value which you want to add or substract.